# Should I install an interior vapor barrier when an exterior barrier is present?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I have a wall on the first floor of my house that is very close to another building, but they are not connected. This wall has an exterior black vapor barrier in the outside and the sheathing is treated plywood on that wall. I live in Michigan, and my question is if I should leave a vapor barrier off the inside on that wall. I was planning to use unfaced rock wool (mineral wool) insulation. I know that generally double vapor barriers are bad, so do I do an unfaced insulation? Looking for ideas. Taking the exterior vapor barrier off that first floor wall is not an option.

Comment: Is it a real vapour barrier(like a black poly garbage bag) or a house wrap?  My house wrap is white on the outside and dark grey on the inside.

Comment: It is a black vapor barrier.

Comment: Odd for Michigan.  I know in hot humid climates the vapour barrier is placed on the outside, but in cold climates a breathable wrap on the outside and the barrier on the inside/warm side.

Comment: I imagine it was done by a well-meaning but ignorant someone to waterproof the inaccessible wall.

Comment: "butts up against another building, but they are not connected" a picture to show this would help clarify what that means.

Comment: Would it be better if I didn’t insulate this wall at all? 3/4 of it is right up against another structure (maybe 4” in between.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. What you posted below is not an answer. No, omitting insulation is not a good plan. The fact that your wall is in the vicinity of another wall doesn't change anything.

Comment: I revised your description. "Butts against" implies an end-to-end arrangement in direct contact. That's apparently not what you have.

Comment: Do you have an air conditioner?

Answer (score 0):

Dual vapor barriers are bad, but so is a dew point inside the insulation. Much more moisture will derive from human activity inside the home than will from the outdoor climate during the cold season, and it will condense and soak your insulation. I would still install a plastic vapor barrier on the inside face of the framing. If possible, open the outside of the wall to ventilation in a protected area, such as under a roof overhang.

If you have any means of replacing the outer plastic with a proper breathable membrane, even in part, do it.